# Processing OpenCV vs Open CV

Tags: opencv, processing

**Solution:**

1. Start Processing 64 bit mode (Mac: in Preferences).
2. Sketch/Import Library/Add Library (All the libraries are there: Thank you Processing Team !!!)
3. Install what you want (I took Opencv for processing).
4. Works.
5. Enjoy :)

**Original Question:**

I have OpenCV installed on my system. Finally after a lot of fails and a complete new system install.

Now I saw that there is this Processing OpenCV library:

http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/

Which is awesome and it comes with a Mac installer (10.6). 
Now I am a little concerned if I install this , that the installed and working OpenCV will get some problems.

Last time I installed it multiple times and wrong. Brew complained about different dylibs (which I had multiple times on my system). And it did not work.

So before I break the now working OpenCV, I would like to be sure that this opencv is just for processing and will not break things otherwise.

Any comment would be great.

Thank you.

**Update:**

Thanks to both of the answers.

On the official processing page there are two opencv libraries. 
The one mentioned above and this one: https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing. 
I already installed a version of opencv via brew (in usr/local/Cellar). 
I don't want to install the official java version (which I don't need and broke things before). 
I would like to have a working opencv installation in processing. 
So how can I install the second library (https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing) in Processing.
I tried putting it in the libraries folder of processing and it gave me this error

"No library found for gab.opencv
Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the 'sketchbook' folder."

Comment: it wants opencv1.0 ? that's like 5 1/2 years ago ! horribly outdated, i'd say .. . so yes, highly likely, that it *will* break your current install

Comment: (+1 Even though I'm not a fan of Processing OpenCV) Add your `Solution` as an answer and accept it so this question appears as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

Start Processing 64 bit mode (Mac: in Preferences).
Sketch/Import Library/Add Library (All the libraries are there: Thank you Processing Team !!!)
Install what you want (I took Opencv for processing).
Works.
Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

The ubaa.net library is very old and it doesn't let you use all the features of OpenCV. It was developed when OpenCV didn't support Java development.

I suggest you use the official Java version:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

Processing is very similar to pure Java and you shouldn't have many problems using it directly. From Processing you can use Java classes as well.

This Java interface works in android as well.

UPDATE:
I didn't know about atduskgreg wrappers, but as they are based on the official Java, it might be a very good option. The problem that you have with the libraries folder is that probably you didn't copy the library in the right location. You have to create a "libraries" folder in your "sketchbook" folder (usually located in c:\Users\Your_username\Documents\Processing\libraries) and there copy the folder with the library. At the end you should have something like c:\Users\Your_username\Documents\Processing\libraries\opencv_processing\

Comment: see my update on the question. Thanks for your help.