# Getting OpenCV to work with Processing 2.1.1 on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, opencv, processing, osx-mavericks

Seems like there are problems for a lot of people trying to get OpenCV to work on OSX and Processing 2. First of all, I am downloading OpenCV from here: http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/

I installed the framework, and also moved the library into the correct Processing folder. When I run an example, I get this:

```
[opencv fatal error] library not loaded !
THIS VERSION OF OPENCV LIBRARY REQUIRE ADDITIONAL DEPENDENCIES.
READ THE INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS AT http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/

Verify that you are running in 32-bit mode, the opencv.framework exists in '/Library/Frameworks' folder and the java.library.path property is correctly.

error message: /Users/austinslominski/Documents/Processing/libraries/OpenCV/library/libOpenCV.jnilib: dlopen(/Users/austinslominski/Documents/Processing/libraries/OpenCV/library/libOpenCV.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/austinslominski/Documents/Processing/libraries/OpenCV/library/libOpenCV.jnilib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

A library relies on native code that's not available.
Or only works properly when the sketch is run as a 32-bit  application.
```

It doesn't look like there is a 32 bit option for Processing for me either. Does anybody know of a fix or an alternative? I need to get started on a shape detection project soon.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773904/processing-opencv-vs-open-cv#comment32996082_21773904 may help, but I really wonder why not use OpenCV directly. Its not that hard to understand if you know Java.

Comment: I agree with Nicolás Carlo about using OpenCV directly, but there are other processing libraries out there: http://thefactoryfactory.com/wordpress/?p=1093

Answer (score 1):

That OpenCV wrapper you are trying to use is a bit outdated.

I recommend trying [Greg's OpenCV wrapper](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing). It basically wraps the functions of the official OpenCV java library so it's to use in Processing and it has plenty of helpful examples.

[image: bg substraction]

[image: depth from stereo]

[image: warp perspective]